# 2sxc RequestVerificationToken not present

Tags: 2sxc

So, I have written a quite simple API:
[2sxc get api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch4kz.png)

But when I call this API with the following URL:

```
https://www.domain.nl/api/2sxc/app/Locaties/api/Searchlocaties/locaties?naam=bo
```

I get the following message:

```
{"Message":"Bad Request","ExceptionType":"System.UnauthorizedAccessException","ExceptionMessage":"RequestVerificationToken not present"}
```

I have set the content and app query permissions to SecurityAccessLevel.Anonymous.

I get the same message even when I am logged in and calling the api using javascript.

```
fetch('https://www.domain.nl/api/2sxc/app/Locaties/api/Searchlocaties/locaties?naam=bo')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
```

DNN 9.8 &
2sxc 11.10.1

Has anyone experience this?

Answer (score 1):

All WebApi requests in DNN should include the request verification token in the header, and you usually also need moduleid and tabid.

When using the 2sxc JS API it does this automatically, and the same applies to when using the DNN JS API. But if you use your own call with jQuery or whatever, you must ensure that you add these headers yourself.

You can find various samples here: https://2sxc.org/dnn-tutorials/en/razor/webapi/home

Comment: Thank you for your response! You guys are doing a great job with 2sxc.