# RequestVerificationToken not present when trying to export an app

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

We are having an issue when we attempt to export an app or content type in our websites. Seems to be happening in our local and production environment. When we go to export an app from 2sxc:

[image: screenshot of where we export from]

We get the following error:

[image: RequestVerificationToken not present]

Error is thrown whether you have "include all content-groups" enabled or not. Also throws if you only attempt to export part of the app.

In our local environment we also get the following stacktrace:

```
StackTrace  "   at DotNetNuke.Web.Api.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.ActionFilterAttributeTracer.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<<OnActionExecutingAsyncCore>b__1>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()"
```

Wondering if there is some setting we are missing that is causing this. It is a function we have used heavily in the past when we release apps into test or production systems.

We were running v14.12.03 LTS, but upgraded to v16.07 LTS in the hope it would fix the issue.

I can see there is a post here with the same error ([2sxc RequestVerificationToken not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66037981/2sxc-requestverificationtoken-not-present)), though it is not clear how to resolve the issue in our setup.

Currently running DNN 09.13.01 and 2sxc 16.07 LTS.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We're not aware of this problem. Note that in most cases, the RVT isn't used for export, since it opens a new window and can't include the RVT for this. Could it be a breaking change in Dnn 9.13.01 which accidentally changes how it checks security? Could you verify on a clean install?